# When creating a class I get TypeError: missing 1 required position argument

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload csv files to s3. When I try to create a class around the methods I get a `Type Error: upload_file_to_s3bucket() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_path'`. It successfully works without the class.

```
class S3Upload():

    def __init__(self, filename=TEST_FILE, filetype='.csv'):
        self.filename = filename
        self.type = filetype

    def make_bucket(self, name, acl):
        session = aws_session()
        s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
        return s3_resource.create_bucket(Bucket=name, ACL=acl)

    def upload_file_to_s3bucket(self, bucket_name, file_path):
        session = aws_session()
        s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
        file_dir, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)

        bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
        bucket.upload_file(
        Filename=file_path,
        Key=file_name,
        ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'}
        )

        s3_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{file_name}"
        return s3_url

    s3_url = upload_file_to_s3bucket('mitch-demo', TEST_FILE)
    print(s3_url) # https://mitch-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/simple.csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    S3 = S3Upload(TEST_FILE)
    S3.make_bucket()
    S3.upload_file_to_s3bucket()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `upload_file_to_s3bucket` *in* the class definition? You are calling it as an ordinary function, but it still needs 3 arguments: an instance of `S3Upload`, a bucket name, and a file name.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `s3_url = upload_file_to_s3bucket('mitch-demo', TEST_FILE)` in the class body? What did you *expect* that to do?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
    s3_url = upload_file_to_s3bucket('mitch-demo', TEST_FILE)
```

You pass in two arguments for bucket name and file_path as defined in your method

```
def upload_file_to_s3bucket(self, bucket_name, file_path):
```

But in your later code you don't do that which is why it errors. It actually happens twice... You need to pass in values where I've put comments:

```
S3.make_bucket(#you need to add a name and acl arguments)
S3.upload_file_to_s3bucket(# you need to add bucket name and file path arguments)
```